# SQL Query Inner Join to get 2 items

Tags: mysql, sql-server, inner-join, python-2.5

I need your help with creating an INNER JOIN query.

So i have currently 3 different tables.

```
1. Tablename: Players (ID - PLAYER_NAME)
   Entry:              1    PLAYER_TEST
```

-

```
2. Tablename: Maps (ID - MAP_NAME)
   Entry:           1  MAP_TEST
```

-

```
3. Tablename: Broken (ID - PLAYER_ID - MAP_ID)
                      1       1          1
```

And i want to execute a query which will choose the **NAME** from the Table: **Players** and **NAME** from the Table: **Maps**

So that i would get the output:

```
[PLAYERNAME:'PLAYER_TEST', MAP_NAME:'MAP_TEST']
```

I've tried it with:

```
SELECT players.name, maps.name, xyz FROM broken INNER JOIN players ON recentlybroken.player_id=players.id ORDER BY xyz DESC LIMIT 0,100
```

Comment: You haven't specified `maps` anywhere in your `FROM` clause—hint: *also* join it against `broken` as appropriate.

Comment: @eggyal could you might tell me how it should be correctly written? The best way to learn something is when you got the correct query in front of you.

Comment: Actually, the best way to learn something is trying to figure it out for yourself.  I've pretty much given you the answer... you could at very least *try* using that information to improve your query and see what happens!

Comment: @eggyal Okay, i just tried to change it with your infos.

Answer (score 0):

I will just give it a try:

```
SELECT pp.name, m.name, o.date,FROM broken AS o INNER JOIN players AS pp ON o.player_id  = pp.id INNER JOIN maps         AS  m ON m.map_id = o.id DESC LIMIT 0,100;
```

Comment: Cool.  And does that give you the results you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT 
  players.players_name AS playerName,
  maps.map_name AS mapName
FROM players 
  LEFT JOIN broken ON broken.player_id=players.id 
  LEFT JOIN maps ON broken.map_id=maps.id 
ORDER BY columnname DESC 
LIMIT 0,100
```